# How can I make jstree render nodes as links?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, anchor, jstree

I have a nice jstree that loads data and so on - now I need to **make it do something when you click a node**.

I've succeeded in handling the node_select event, but is there an easy way to make the nodes render as links (as in html <a> tags)?

**Edit:**
It looks like jstree nodes are already links - it uses an <a> tag as well as <li>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jstree nodes are already links - it uses an `<a>` tag as well as `<li>`

Answer (score 5):

```
    .delegate("a","dblclick", function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.google.de",
            data: "id="+$(this).parent().get(0).id,
            success: function(data){
            $("#ajaxcontent").html(data);
        }
        });
    })
```